# Can't NoSQL DB ensure consistency if it is residing in a single server?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

As NoSQL DBs always prefer BASE over ACID.

Everyone always says that you can't have ACID when you are working with a NoSQL DBs.

For example, we have MongoDB (a popular NoSQL DB), which is hosted within a single server. No replicas. If the client app updates a document, strong consistency should take place.

(Just curious, not expert)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a write to a single instance, distributed database will be immediately consistent.  You likely still won't have ACID, as each NoSQL variant has its own ways of handling (or not) atomicity.

Although, I have to wonder what the goal would be here.  The main feature of a NoSQL database is its ability to support partition tolerance...which is lost in a single instance configuration.  I can't think of many scenarios like that where I wouldn't just run Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct, inherently you end up with strong consistency because the use case is a single node server as opposed to a cluster.

Conversely there are **RDBMS** that offer consistency across multi-node clusters or quasi-hybrids of the **BASE** and **ACID** principals nowadays too.

Everything is fair game, there's a lot of blurred lines, and using **NoSQL** in a single server is pretty normal and will automatically offer consistency since there's nothing to replicate to.

Answer (score 0):

What "Everyone" says isn't true!

A related issue was discussed on this forum recently ("If NoSQL stands for "Not only SQL", is SQL a subset of NoSQL?"), and in my answer, I mention 2 KV systems, one of which ([RocksDB](https://rocksdb.org/blog/)) has a subset of ACID transaction characteristics and one of which has them **ALL** ([FoundationDB](https://thenewstack.io/foundationdb-a-reliable-key-value-store-with-acid-compliance/)).

BTW, MongoDB is **NOT** fully ACID compliant - see the report from the highly respected JESPEN site [here](https://jepsen.io/analyses). There is further reading to be done [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185763/why-are-nosql-databases-not-acid-compliant) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608103/is-there-any-nosql-data-store-that-is-acid-compliant) - but there is nothing to stop a system which fully supports SQL from being BASE and vice-versa...

And remember, don't believe everything a vendor tells you - they (ahem...) **may** be biased.

Also, don't forget that BASE is a perfectly valid strategy - for the likes of Amazon and/or Facebook where the odd cancelled order and/or lost post isn't going to be the end of the world - however, banks **cannot** (afford) to think like that - their systems **have** to be ACID - at least the ones handling financial transactions - maybe they perform their customer loyalty programmmes on a BASE system - lower machine specs and no requirement to maintain consensus/correctness leads to lower costs!